# Очистка загруженных файлов после случайного обновления страницы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

При создании новой темы на форуме пользователь имеет возможность прикрепить к своему сообщению файл. Он нажимает кнопку ЗАГРУЗИТЬ ФАЙЛ, и после его загрузки файл помещается на страницу в виде иконки или маленькой превьюшки. Затем, после заполнения нужных форм, пользователь нажимает кнопку ОТПРАВИТЬ, и его новая тема вместе с загруженной картинкой помещается на форум.

Важный момент. Когда пользователь загружает в форму файл, этот файл появляется на странице в виде превьюшки. Но если обновить страницу, то файл пропадает со страницы, и приходится загружать файл заново.

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ, чтобы при перезагрузке страницы файл всё-таки оставался в форме создания новой темы?

Comment: Или хотя бы можно как-то удалить этот загруженный в форму файлы, если пользовать обновил страницу?

Comment: Для каких целей перезагружать страницу, если в форму добавлен файл, и в форме набирается текст для оправки.

Comment: Цели в перезагрузке страницы нет. Но пользователи могут это делать. А дисковое пространство на сервере ограниченное.

Comment: @stashappy, почему вы должны решать проблемы пользователей :)

Comment: Я хочу решить проблему экономии дискового пространства.;)

Comment: Можно сделать костыли и как-то хранить информацию о файлах этих, но как по мне проще к этой теме добавлять информацию о загруженном файле.

Потом создать задание (cron, etc..) которое будет проверять все ли файлы привязаны к теме, если нет - удалять их!

Answer (score 1):

Когда файл прикрепили, помещайте файл в временную папку. А после добавления темы перемещайте в нужную директорию. Все ненужные файлы будут тогда в временной папке. Вам тогда нужно будет раз в неделю (месяц) удалять все из временной папки.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартными средствами никак. Да и нигде реализации подобных вещей не видел

Comment: Такое есть Вконтакте.

Comment: Ко мне пришла следующая идея. Мы создаём в корневой папке нашего сайта, каталог под названием tmp. В него мы будем копировать загружаемый пользователем файл из временной директории сервера. А далее, когда пользователь нажимает в форме кнопку ОТПРАВИТЬ, мы копируем его загруженный файл из папки tmp, в ЕГО пользовательскую папку, которая является конечной.

И это ещё не всё. Мы вешаем на сервере CRON, который каждые 10 минут будет очищать нашу созданную папку tmp по маске.

По идее это должно сработать. Теперь наш сервер не будет переполняться загруженными, но неиспользуемыми файлами.

Comment: @stashappy, проще делать unlink() после загрузки, чем ставить крон задание, так как вдруг кто-то во время очистки будет добавлять файл.

Comment: Да. Но мы не сможем сделать unlink(), если пользователь обновит страницу. Его загруженные файлы так и останутся лежать на сервере. А ему придётся загружать файлы заного.

Comment: @stashappy, записывай данные файла из папки tmp в сессию, после загрузки просто очищай её и удаляй файл. В чем проблема-то :)

Comment: Сессиями, конечно, можно. Проверять, что у нас в сессиях, и выводить данные в форму, если в них что-то есть. Но на сайте есть также формы редактирования записей. В них пользователь тоже может загружать файлы. Он может загрузить файлы в форму редактирвания и нажать кнопку обновления страницы. И тогда его файлы пропадут, как и сама форма редактирования. Так как сама форма была вызвана ajax запросом.

Что если сделать так, как предложил нам myvzar. Но только с использованием CRON'а. И чтобы не каждый месяц он проверял файлы, а каждый час. Чтобы при проверке файлов он смотрел дату изменения файла

Comment: @stashappy, мы вам ничем помочь не можем, тут всё от вашей фантазии зависит, так как способов много :)

Answer (score 0):

Я написал скрипт, который вешается на CRON, с периодичностью выполнения: один запуск в каждые полдня. Скрипт проверяет дату последнего изменения файла. Если дата изменения файла больше, чем 6 часов, то скрипт удаляет этот файл.

```
$dir = "tmp/";
if(is_dir($dir)) {
    if($descriptor = opendir($dir)) {
        while(($file = readdir($descriptor))) {
            if($file !== false) {
                if($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                    if(is_file($dir."/".$file)) {
                        if(file_exists($dir."/".$file)) {
                            $file_time = filemtime($dir."/".$file);
                            if((time()-$file_time) > 6*60*60) { // 6 часов
                                unlink($dir."/".$file);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            usleep(10);
        }
        closedir($descriptor);
    }
} else {
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Пробовал этот код у себя на локальном сервере. Чтобы удалить с его помощью 6 тысяч файлов, потребовалось ждать где-то 25 секунд. Учитывая, что я вставил задержку на каждой итерации в 10 микросекунд. Что вы думаете по поводу таково варианта? Что если файлов будет намного больше, чем 6 тысяч...

Comment: ![](http://i.imgur.com/UGlBPzY.jpg)

Comment: Это намёк на использование сессий? Я уже упомянул выше, что в моём случае они не очень удобны. Потому что в проекте имеются формы редактирования постов. Они вызываются ajax запросом. А следовательно при обновлении страницы, из формы редактирования пропадут загруженные файлы, вместе с самой формой.

Comment: Да и можно было не тратить время на написание такой очистки папки, а взять готовую, и причем не большую функцию :)

http://code-snippets.ru/home/php/ochistit-papku.html

Comment: У меня практически всё тоже самое, но без удаления директорий(rmdir) и с проверкой на последнее изменение файла. Если время изменения больше 6 часов, файл удаляется. К тому же тот вариант удаления не совсем приемлем. Так как функция scandir возвратит огромный массив, в случае если файлов будет очень много. К чему нам это.

Comment: @stashappy, ну смотрите

    if($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        if(is_file($dir."/".$file)) {

. и .. - это гарантированно не файлы. Требуется всего лишь последняя проверка из этих трех.


    if(file_exists($dir."/".$file)) {

мы только что проверили функцией `is_file`, что он существует. Другими словами, три проверки уже можно выкинуть, чтобы облегчить читаемость. Но можно еще круче:

    while(($file = readdir($descriptor))) {
        if (!$file || !is_file($dir . '/' . $file)) {
            continue;
        }
        // и никакой лишней индентации
        $modTime = filemtime()

Comment: @stashappy но можно и еще круче

    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fsNode) {
        if (!$fsNode->isFile()) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($fsNode->getMTime() < time() - 6* 3600) {
            unlink($fsNode->getPathname()); // тут, если не ошибаюсь, может понадобиться сначала сделать unset для $fsNode, потому что в этот момент файл открыт в файловой системе
        }
    }

Comment: Да. Так намного лучше.:) Хотя признаться честно, я и сам смотрю на эти лишние проверки и не шипко они глаз радуют.:) С удалением файлов разобрались. Благодарю вас. Код я исправил. Какие мысли возникают насчёт самой идеи? То есть, идея повесить на CRON php-файл, который очищает те файлы, время последнего изменения которых больше 6 часов.

Comment: @stashappy

> То есть, идея повесить на CRON php-файл, который очищает те файлы, время последнего изменения которых больше 6 часов.

Все так и делают, разве что когда с файлами связана какая-то сложная логика и тогда надо вытаскивать информацию о них из БД - но всё равно это почти всегда висит на кроне